# How one explain the formation of interference in the intersection of rays from images ? Is wave nature is getting considered?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, lenses

Setup below shows a (modified billet split lens setup) where two point light sources which emits wavelengths of same value and also they are in phase [Assume] . Now consider the rays which are getting emitted from those and are making images at other side of lens and then making possible the interference pattern observable in the screen subjected to the suitable distance the screen is placed so that some interference from both rays can take place on the screen . Now my question is are we considering just the ray optics here so that the images rays are responsible for interference to show up ? Or is that wave optics is being considered when the intereference pattern forming is there in the screen ?  If the wave optics is being is considered will not the images will act themselves as source of light waves which will cause intereference pattern to be shown in the wholse screen like in normal YDSE ? How one explain the intereference pattern formation in just that intersection portion is it due to light being considered as rays or waves too ?[image]

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700709/2451

Answer (score 0):

All the waves comonpfrom one point go through the image point, and this are only the ones which pss the lens. so only the waves coming from the  two image points can interfere . an they only overlap in the marked region. The "rays" just tell you the maximum spread of the waves.